# Closure with multiple methods in python

Tags: python, closures

I am trying to write a class object in python which has attributes which are closure functions able to modify a private string, I understand closures for the most part but I cannot get it to work with more than one. I am trying to return an array of function but i get

```
local variable 'string' referenced before assignment
```

indicating to me that either the string variable is destroyed or the functions are not retaining their closure status and being able to access it. The get_val function seems to work and I tried adding global declarations but either this is not the issue or I could not get it to work right.

```
class StringUpdater:
    def _(self):
        string = "MI"
        def get_val():
            return string
        def add_u(): 
            if string.endswith("I"):
                string+="U"      
        def add_two_through_last():
            string+=string[1:]
        def replace_III_with_U():
            #global string
            string.replace("III", "U")
        def remove_UU():
            #global string
            string.replace("UU", "")
        return [get_val,add_u,add_two_through_last,replace_III_with_U,remove_UU]

    def __init__(self):
        str_obj = self._()
        self.get_val = str_obj[0]
        self.add_u = str_obj[1]
        self.add_two_through_last = str_obj[2]
        self.replace_III_with_U = str_obj[3]
        self.remove_UU = str_obj[4] 


f = StringUpdater()
print f.add_two_through_last()
print f.get_val()
```

Comment: you are correct about closure. your code should generally work in fp languages. this annoying problem is introduced by python legb scoping.

Comment: have a look at http://embrangler.com/2011/01/python-scoping-understading-legb/. exactly the same problem.

Comment: thanks for the article but I don't think his solution works for my problem, his still fails to modify the original variable

Comment: are there any alternative methods for using multi-function closures in python?

Comment: your problem is that strings are immutable in python. (and as a side note, please never name a variable `string`.)

Comment: @FFF in your case, i am sorry i really don't know how to let you modify that variable(maybe it's no way to modify it since the lack of certain keyword). but in the fp semantics, it's better to keep it immutable, that is, keep the object the way when they are born.

Comment: note that for example `string.replace` never modifies `string`, closure or not - it's by design.

Comment: @ch3ka thanks this is something I overlooked, and yeah I knew someone would call me out on that, I had it called str in a different version, also thanks for the note about replace overlooked that aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error `string referenced before assignment` is that inside of `add_u` you are trying to write to a variable called `string` via the `+=` operator, so Python is creating a new local variable inside of `add_u`, which is different from the variable in `_`.

This can be solved by a `nonlocal` in Python 3, but if you are stuck with Python 2, I would just wrap the "outer" `string` in an array.  I would say this is a fairly common pattern to use in Python, but most of the time Python isn't really used in a functional way, although it is perfectly capable of implementing closures.

To show how this would work, I simplified things a little and ditched the `class`, making a dictionary of functions that use the closed over string.  In order to *write* to that very string, I stuck it in an array:

```
def _mu():
    data = ["MI"]
    def rule1():
        if data[0].endswith('I'): data[0] += 'U'
    def rule2():
        data[0] += data[0][1:]
    def rule3():
        data[0] = data[0].replace('III', 'U')
    def rule4():
        data[0] = data[0].replace('UU', '')
    return {
        'value': lambda: data[0],
        'rule1': rule1,
        'rule2': rule2,
        'rule3': rule3,
        'rule4': rule4}

mu = _mu()
```

I'm calling it `mu` since these rules are recognizable as the [MU-Puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle).

Now you can write:

```
mu['value']() # => 'MI'
mu['rule1']()
mu['value']() # => 'MIU'
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on this similar approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766679/2647672

Answer (score 1):

following is a way how you can perform OO encapsulation in FP way. note that fp is an art of immutability:

```
def encap_str(s):
    def get():
        return s
    def append(s_):
        return encap_str(s + s_)
    def replace(s1, s2):
        return encap_str(s.replace(s1, s2))
    def encap(fname):
        return {'get': get,
                'append': append,
                'replace': replace}[fname]
    return encap
```

test:

```
>>> o=encap_str('12345678')
>>> o('append')('90')('get')()
'1234567890'
>>> encap_str('aaabbbcccddd')('replace')('bbb', 'zzz')('get')()
'aaazzzcccddd'
```

for more, please reference to SICP, http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

---

following is some of my opnion

python doesn't seem to encourage you to perform FP. as you may know, `lambda` in python is weakened, it is not meant to have the same power as normal functions. and the legb scoping is kind of necessary but annoying. so if you want to understand FP, python is not a good platform.

to make a comparison, `Perl` support FP perfectly well. following is a demo in `Perl`:

```
package OOinPerl;  

sub new{  
        my $self=shift;  
        my $type=ref $self || $self;  
        #... somehow fetch the parameters from @_ and save in $a, $b and $c.  
        my $data={a=>$a,b=>$b,c=>$c};  #this is a hash table reference  
        my $this=sub{  
                my $field=shift;  
                $data->{$field}=shift if @_;  
                $data->{$field}  
        };  
        bless $this, $type  
}  

#... other functions
```

here, an object is actually a lambda, and a lambda allows modification to internal data(`$data`). but real OO in `Perl`, to be honest, sucks.

personally recommend you [SML/NJ](http://www.smlnj.org/).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is the same as [Ray Toal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393932/2647672), but eschews the `dict['key']` notation for what I feel is a cleaner `function.attribute` notation. You do this by (ab)using the fact that python functions can be assigned attributes using `function.attribute = value`.

I'll use Ray Toal's example so you can see the difference.

```
def _mu():
    data = ["MI"]
    def rule1():
        if data[0].endswith('I'): data[0] += 'U'
    def rule2():
        data[0] += data[0][1:]
    def rule3():
        data[0] = data[0].replace('III', 'U')
    def rule4():
        data[0] = data[0].replace('UU', '')

    _mu.value = lambda: data[0]
    _mu.rule1 = rule1 
    _mu.rule2 = rule2
    _mu.rule3 = rule3
    _mu.rule4 = rule4
    return _mu

mu = _mu()

mu.value() # => 'MI'
mu.rule1()
mu.value() # => 'MIU'
```

You reuse `_mu` to assign it variables or functions, treating it as a container. To me, it seems similar to the OOP use of the `self` variable. Also note that `_mu.__dict__` allows you to access the attributes as you would a dictionary if you need to.

I don't know much about the performance of this versus the dictionary approach, but this method may be equivalent because afaik attributes are stored in a dictionary.

Lastly, I don't know if assigning attributes to `_mu` within itself would create some kind of problem, but if it does, you can add a dummy function to act as a `container`, then instead of assigning to `_mu`, you assign to that `container`:

```
    container = lambda: None
    container.value = lambda: data[0]
    container.rule1 = rule1 
    container.rule2 = rule2
    container.rule3 = rule3
    container.rule4 = rule4
    return container
```